# How to bin time point and average the data for several subjects?

Tags: r, time, average, bin

Here is my file:

[image: blood pressure data every second]

`time3` is going from around -3600 to +400-600ms. I need to bin this `time3` in 20 seconds window with the `0` time point staying as `0` and not being in the middle of a window. Then I need to do a mean of `reSYS` for each 20 sec windows. 
I need to do this for each `Subject` (`"DL001"` to `"DL028"`) and each `condition` (`"Light"` or `"control"`).

I tried several options, the closer one is this one:

```
data3 <- data2 %>% 
  group_by(time3 = cut(time3, breaks=205, include.lowest = TRUE)) %>%
  summarize(RR_int.mean = mean(RR_int))
```

But the 20 sec window start with the first time point that appears `-3599.312` and goes all the way up, such that the `0` time point is in a window between `-9` and `+11`. It average all the values from all the subjects together as well instead of doing it for each subject separately.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Don't post data as images. Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: If you want a mean of `reSYS` then why `mean(RR_int)`?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say without an example dataset but try the following.

Define a breaks vector that includes the zero and goes up or down from there.

```
brk_time3 <- with(data2, unique(c(rev(seq(0, min(time3), by = -20)), seq(0, max(time3), by = 20))))
```

Now it's a simple `group_by/summarize`.

```
data3 <- data2 %>%
    group_by(time3 = cut(time3, breaks = brk_time3, include.lowest = TRUE), Subject, condition) %>%
    summarize(mean.reSYS = mean(reSYS))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was really helpful and working actually!